# Why the alert in this script is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, alert, var

I want to get some information of the text given in the document into variables, and insert them into an alert for verification, but the alert is not working. Why does this happen?

Here is the portion of the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

var enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var numero = enlaces.length();
var dir = enlaces[numero-2].href;
var contador = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= enlaces.length-1; i++) {
    if(enlaces[i].href = "http://prueba" || enlaces[i].href = "http://prueba/")
        contador++;
};

var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var enlacesTercerParrafo = parrafos[2].getElementsByTagName("a").length;

alert("El numero de enlaces es:");

}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Check your errors, the script must have exited because of one before the alert.

Comment: `nlaces[i].href =` or `nlaces[i].href ==`?

Comment: `var numero = enlaces.length();` should be `var numero = enlaces.length;`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 5):

There should not be () after .length; it should be like this:

```
var numero = enlaces.length;
```

Comment: And also `enlaces[i].href = "http://prueba"` should be using `==` (or `===`).

Answer (score 3):

Try == operator for comparison

```
if(enlaces[i].href == "http://prueba" || enlaces[i].href == "http://prueba/")
```

Comment: While this wouldn't cause an error, it definitely needs to be fixed. Doesn't deserve a down-vote IMO.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Actually it would generate an invalid lefthand assignment.

Comment: @cookiemonster it would throw `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Comment: @j08691: Ah right. Because of the `||` and operator precedence.

Comment: I'm starting with Javascript and I'm doing a lot of silly mistakes. Thank you all.